# Catch wzzip return codes in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, command-line, winzip

I currently have a PowerShell script that zips items that aren't already in a specified folder. I need my script to return `wzzip`'s error codes if one is thrown, so I can handle it in the rest of my script. I've provided a bit of my script below:

```
foreach ($File in Get-ChildItem $Path\$Item -Recurse | Where {$_.PSIsContainer -ne $true}) {
    WZZIP.EXE $Path\$Item.zip $File.FullName
}
```

Comment: `$var = start-process -filepath wzzip.exe -argumentlist '...' -passthru -wait` and then `$var.ExitCode`

Comment: If you need to zip a file, I'd suggest using the `Compress-Archive` cmdlet if you're on v5, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell automatically stores the exit code of external programs in the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0) `$LASTEXITCODE`.

```
WZZIP.EXE ...
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
    # do stuff here
}
```